# C# HTMLAgilityPack Select not contains

Tags: c#, xpath, console, html-agility-pack

My program is a simple c# console application, I am unsure of howto achieve my goal, basically I am selecting a single node but I would like to ignore an  tag with a particular text value, my code is below.

```
string name = item.SelectSingleNode("//select[contains(@id,'var')]//option")
                  .GetInnerTextFromNode();
```

I know in jQuery you could use :not filter, but not sure in C# and I have search for documentation for the pack, but nothing has surfaced.

Thank you

Comment: You're looking for the `not()` operator. The syntax parsed by the HTML Agility Pack is actually XPath, so if you search for that you should find a lot more answers :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024080/how-to-use-not-contains-in-xpath

Comment: Thank you that work's a treat!

Answer (score 3):

Simply taking RGraham's comment and turning it into an answer:

```
 string name = item.SelectSingleNode("//select[not(contains(@id,'var'))]//option")
              .GetInnerTextFromNode();
```

As for guidance on what kind of functions you can use, check out the [w3schools XPath tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp).

Comment: Thank you for that, unfortunately I am unable to 1 up the comment.

Comment: If you just transformed the comment to an answer (which it should be), you should probably mark it as "community wiki".

Comment: @jens, no idea how to do that.

Comment: There is a small check box when editing your post. There's also a [page in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).