# How to use xpath 'not' statement in Selenium?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, xpath

I am using selenium to automate some test cases but I am having some issues finding some elements that don't have a certain style. I have created this Xpath that works perfectly in Chrome but when I run it using selenium it doesn't work as I want.

XPATH: `./td[not(contains(@style, 'foo'))]`

So basicaly the HTML looks like this:

```
<tr id='something'>
   <td style='foo'><td/>
   <td style='foo'><td/>
   <td style='foo'><td/>
   <td style='foo'><td/>
   ...
   <td>1<td/>
   <td>2<td/>
   <td>3<td/>
</tr>
```

So basically I want the last 3 tds so First I get the row and then I sent the Xpath. . . something like this:

```
var row = driver.FinElement(By.Id("something"));
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> items = row.FindElements(By.Xpath(./td[not(contains(@style, 'foo'))];
```

But as a result I am getting all the children of the tr.

Any Idea why the Xpath is working on Chrome developer tools and don't  work with selenimun IE driver?

Comment: could you try `.//td[not(contains(@style, 'foo')`

Comment: are you sure IE supports XPATH at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to Chrome, IE formats the style attribute.
For instance, if the style in the HTML is:

```
<td style='DISPLAY:BLOCK;'>
```

IE will change it to:

```
<td style='display: block;'>
```

So with Chrome `//td[@style='DISPLAY:BLOCK;']` will return a match and IE will return no match.

Now, with your example, on solution to get the last 3 elements would be to get all the `<td>` without a style attribute:

```xpath
./td[not(@style)]
```

You could also normalize the casing and remove the spaces with `translate`:

```xpath
./td[not(contains(translate(@style,'FO ','fo'), 'foo'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Could you try following :

   ```
   .//td[not(contains(@style, 'foo')  // double back slash for child element
   ```

from the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/) to access the child

2. Please make sure that you are not mis matching the case since `contains` is case-sensitive. Answer to [How to use not contains() in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024080/how-to-use-not-contains-in-xpath)