# Search for a line that does NOT contain a certain expression (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following line of code is used to search for lines of source code that contains the text "#":

```
XPATH_RANK = '//span[contains(text(),"#")]//text()'
```

How can I modify this particular line of code to IGNORE certain text?

Please keep in mind that I know next to nothing about Python, and am only learning as I go along with this project for work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`'//span[not(contains(text(),"#"))]//text()'`

This question is a duplicate of [How to use not contains() in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024080/how-to-use-not-contains-in-xpath) but here's your use.

Comment: Thank you.  How can I use this to use certain text but ignore others?  For example, what I want to do is have this line use text that contains "#" but ignore text that contains the string "#1 Best Seller".

This is what I have right now:

`'//span[contains(text(),"#") and not(contains(text(),"#1 Best Seller"))]//text'`


Is this correct?  If it is, it's not doing what I want it to.

Comment: you can use multiple square bracket operations. so:
`//span[contains(text(),"#")][not(contains(text,"#1 Best Seller"))]`

Comment: If you are new to building XPATHs, consider sandboxing here: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output . Much like regexes, practice  and experience help a lot, and using a sandbox is faster than running code every time. Plus this one gives hints.