# Selenium Automation : Identifying unique set of webelements using selenium in JAVA

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have an HTML like this:

```
"<div **id="xx-abc-list-1"**>
<button ng-reflect-class-base="icon component" **id="xx-abc-list-button-2"**><span class="mat-button-wrapper">
</div>

<div **id="xx-abc-list-2"**>
<button ng-reflect-class-base="icon component" **id="xx-abc-list-button-2"**><span class="mat-button-wrapper">
</div>"
```

Now, i wanted to get the list of all the elements ending with id = xx-abc-list- only so i used the below code.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@id,'xx-abc-list-')]");
List<WebElement>;
```

But this gives me 4 count considering other elements (xx-abc-list-button-) as well.

What should i modify in my above code to get just 2 values that i need?

Answer (score 4):

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@id,'xx-abc-list-')]");
```

The `*` in your XPath above indicates any element (it's a wildcard). In your case, you want only `DIV`s so you can change that to

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@id,'xx-abc-list-')]");
```

and it should get you what you want.

In a more complicated scenario where you want two but not the four and all are `DIV`s, you can still use a "not contains()" to exclude the IDs that contain "-button-".

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@id,'xx-abc-list-')][not(contains(@id,'-button-'))]")
```

[How to use not contains() in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024080/how-to-use-not-contains-in-xpath)

Comment: Great. If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.